# How to show formatted/indented HTML code in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, jupyter

Is it possible to output formatted raw HTML code in Jupyter as with `prettify` from BeautifulSoup?

When I call `prettify` in Jupyter, it gives me the same messy output as with simply calling `.content` on the result I get from `requests.get`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to use a print?

Jupyter (like ipython) calls the `__repr__` method for the result of the operation.

In this case, it's the `__repr__` of a string, which adds the simple quotes and escapes the special characters (\n, \t...) so they are not interpreted.

But those characters are interpreted with print

Comment: Yes print worked! I just read more on `__repr__` of strings.  Thank you for the info.